# Bookmarkable PrimeFaces datatable paginator

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, pagination, bookmarks

Is there any way to implement bookmarkable paginator for `<p:dataTable>` from PrimeFaces? For example, on `<p:dataTable>` with `row="10"` when I press the pagination button to second page the url becomes http://example.com/list.xhtml?first=10&max=10.

Comment: You need a custom paginator renderer.

Comment: @BalusC No other way?

Comment: A custom component can also, but that's only more work. If you absolutely don't want to do anything, just post an enhancement request to PrimeFaces guys.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create it yourself as far as I know. So if you want to have the same pagination template as in primefaces example you will have to recreate the css.

To create a custom one it is pretty simple:
First paginator of datatable is set to false, because you gonna make a custom one.
Then make two links on top of your dataTable:

this is from new.xhtml:

```
<div class="nextPrevBlock">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{page>0}" style="margin-right:1em;">
        <h:link outcome="new.xhtml">
            <f:param name="page" value="#{page - 1}"/>
            <div class="btnLink">
                <h:outputText value="#{strings.previous}"></h:outputText>
            </div>
        </h:link>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:link outcome="new.xhtml">
            <f:param name="page" value="#{page + 1}"/>
            <div class="btnLink">
                <h:outputText value="#{strings.next}"/>
            </div>
        </h:link>
    </h:panelGroup>
</div>
```

Store the page in your Managed Bean with getters and setters.
Then just query with the page:

```
//it's requestScoped
@EJB
private ElemService elementService;
private List<Element> elementList;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> paramsMap = fc.getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap();
    try {
        page = Integer.parseInt(paramsMap.get("page"));
        if (page < 0)
            page = 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      page = 0;
    }
    getElementsOfPage(page);
}
public void getElementsOfPage(int page) {
    elementList = elementService.getElemByPage(page);
}
```

Then in your service :

```
@Override
public List<Element> giveElementList(int page) {
    Query query = em.createQuery(SELECT_NEWEST_THREADS);
    query.setFirstResult(page * NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE);
    query.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_PER_PAGE);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

`setFirstResult()` is the first result so you have to put the value of the page times the elem by page. And `setMaxResults` is just the elem by page you want.

You will have to customize it though so it suits your needs.
I hope this help.

Comment: OP is talking about `<p:dataTable paginator="true">`.

Comment: @BalusC yeah I understood but maybe this will help, I had the code open in a project already so I thought it wouldn't hurt to just post it. Beside the end goal is the same as far as I understand. He wants a pagination system, I believe op doesn't care if paginator is set to true or not.

Comment: Lazy loading part is already covered by `<p:dataTable lazy="true">`. Answer would be nicer if you just based the answer on `<p:dataTable lazy="true">` (or not lazy, that's after all actually not relevant to the paginator itself as all it needs to do is to control the datatable's `first` property, this can be done with pure XHTML).

Comment: @BalusC This is great. I'll update my answer when I learn more about this. It might take me some time though. Feel free to edit me if you feel like it's needed.

Comment: @BalusC I'm not sure what you meant by your comment. Did you mean that he could overwritte the ´first´ property in the load method of the lazy datamodel ? With the paginator set to true or with a custom one like I posted ?

Comment: No. E.g. `<p:dataTable first="#{param.first}">`. Remainder will go all by itself.